Getting wrong CPU Processor ID with __cpuid() in Win 11 systems
I am facing an issue in getting CPU Processor ID with C++ code.
I used __cpuid() function as below:
#include <iostream>
#include <intrin.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned __int32  regs[4];
    __cpuid((int *)regs, 1);
    std::cout << "Processor ID: " << std::hex << regs[3] << " 000 " << regs[0];
}

This code is working in all the Win 10 systems.
But some Win 11 systems are providing EDX data (regs[3] in above code) as BFCBFBFF.
When I use "wmic cpu get processorid" at command prompt, I got BFEBFBFF.
Is it issue with Win 11 system or __cpuid function or any mistake in my code?
Config for Ref:
Processor: 12th Gen Intel (R) Core(TM) i7-12700 2.10 GHz,
System Type: 64 bit OS, x64-based processor,
OS: Win 11 Pro 22H2, Build: 22621.3880
Thanks in advance
Bhanodaya

The bit you are mentioning appears to be the "debug store" bit (DS) (EDX, bit 21; got that bit number because 0xBFEBFBFF-0xBFCBFBFF == 0x200000, which is 1 << 21). Since wmic gives you the correct output, it appears to me that the kernel is intercepting the cpuid instruction from your programs and filtering out that bit. Could it be some third-party software (virus scanner or other security application) that does this, since it's not all Windows 11 systems? Don't know how to help you further here, but maybe this will help someone else figure this out.

Could be Windows 11 Virtualization Based Security. Then, the value returned is effectively correct - Windows masks off the features in CPUID which are disabled for security reasons.

@chris_se: Intercepting CPUID is easily possible if it's using HW virtualization.  CPUID is always a VM-exit.  IDK if there's a way to make CPUID trap without VMENTER and so on, but I think modern Windows might use hardware virtualization even if you aren't intentionally running in a VM?  Anyway, that's how it's technically possible, and MSalters's comment suggests why.

Thanks friends for your efforts. I await the root cause and solution.
